# d3.js pass user select input value as csv column name in d3.csvParse callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on this visualization at
https://observablehq.com/d/88fa7afb1d32ebc8
below is the spot that I am trying to flesh out with user input from a drop down menu

```
dataRaw = Object.assign(
  new Map(d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("DATA.csv").text(),  
//want to make csvColumnName on line below dynamic 
  ({objKey, csvColumnName}) => [objKey, +csvColumnName])), 
  {title: " "+SelectOptions.filter( (stat) => stat.value.key === mySelect.key)[0].label})
```

I want the csv to be parsed based on what the user selects.

I can get csv column names back from the select, but as strings.
Below is what I have tried

```
mySelect.key = "userInputCsvCol1Name";
....
  d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("covid19-dec16@4.csv").text(), 
    ({objKey, csvColumnName}) => [objKey, +(mySelect.key)]  //<-------can't be a string 
  )
```

I am pretty new to Javascript, is there a way to rewrite this so I can build the object dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by going step by step in the notebook and breaking up the function

first I got the file and parsed the csv

```
x = await FileAttachment("covid19-dec16@4.csv").text()
y = d3.csvParse(x)
```

then I created 2 arrays, with the second being the user input from a select dropdown and finally iterated over them to create the final map to use in the chart

```
map1 = y.map(d=>  d["objKey"] )
map2 = y.map(d=>  +d[mySelect.key])


let obj =new Map();
  let k
  for (let i = 0; i < map1 .length; i++) {
       obj.set(yy[i], xx[i]); 
  }
```

see it in action here thanks
https://observablehq.com/@josephhailu/untitled/3